# Query is not getting all mysql_fetch_assocs's

Tags: php

Could someone tell me why the following bit of code only gets all images in the query except for the last?

```
    $userquery  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM acceptedfriends WHERE    profilename='$profilename' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4");
    while ($userrun = mysql_fetch_assoc($userquery))
    {
        $users = $userrun['username'];
        $imagequery  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users2 WHERE username='$users'");
        while ($imagefetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($imagequery))
        {
            $location = $imagefetch['imagelocation'];
            $image = "<img src='$location' width='60' height='40'>";
            if ($profilename==$username)
            {
                echo '<div id="hovercolor2" style="width:294px; float:left;"><table><tr>    <td>'.$image.'</td><td><div style="margin-bottom:5px;"><a    href="http://www.pearlsquirrel.com/'.$users.'" target="_blank">'.$users.'</a></div><div><a href="http://www.pearlsquirrel.com/conversation.php/'.$users.'" style="text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank"><div style="font-size:.7em";>Click to enter a conversation.</div></a></div></td></tr></table></div><div id="hrdiv3" style="float:left; width:298px;"></div>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<div id="hovercolor2" style="width:294px; float:left;"><table><tr><td>'.$image.'</td><td><a href="http://www.pearlsquirrel.com/'.$users.'" target="_blank">'.$users.'</a></td></tr></table></div><div id="hrdiv3" style="float:left; width:298px;"></div>';
            }
        }
    }
```

This

```
$image = "<img src='$location' width='60' height='40'>";
```

is not getting the last image in the query.  I have spend about and hour trying to solve this and have no idea.  Any help would be appreciated.

Simplified code with the same error

```
    $userquery  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM acceptedfriends WHERE     profilename='$profilename' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6");
    while ($userrun = mysql_fetch_assoc($userquery))
    {
        $users = $userrun['username'];
        $location = $userrun['imagelocation'];
        $image = "<img src='$location' style='width:60px; height:40px;'>";
        if ($profilename==$username)
        {
            echo '<div id="hovercolor2" style="width:294px; float:left;"><table><tr><td>'.$image.'</td><td><div style="margin-bottom:5px;"><a href="http://www.pearlsquirrel.com/'.$users.'" target="_blank">'.$users.'</a></div><div><a href="http://www.pearlsquirrel.com/conversation.php/'.$pageusers.'" style="text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank"><div style="font-size:.7em";>Click to enter a conversation.</div></a></div></td></tr></table></div><div id="hrdiv3" style="float:left; width:298px;"></div>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<div id="hovercolor2" style="width:294px; float:left;"><table><tr><td>'.$image.'</td><td><a href="http://www.pearlsquirrel.com/'.$users.'" target="_blank">'.$users.'</a></td></tr></table></div><div id="hrdiv3" style="float:left; width:298px;"></div>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you it's not getting the last image? use mysql_num_rows() to get the number of rows return, from there we can investigate further.

Comment: so you're only getting 3 images? and by the by, `$image = "<img src='$location' width='60' height='40'>";` really should be `$image = "<img src='$location' width='60' height='40' />";` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens when you run a print_r(mysql_fetch_assoc($userquery)); on both select statements? Do you see the data in the array? I'm assuming your doing the LIMIT 4 on purpose? Normally I don't run a while loop inside of another, you can try this instead:

```
$userquery  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM acceptedfriends WHERE profilename='$profilename' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4");

while ($userrun = mysql_fetch_assoc($userquery)) {
    $userArray[] = $userrun;
}

print_r($userArray);
echo '<br /><br />';

foreach ($userArray as $userValue) {
    $users = $userValue['username'];
    $imagequery  = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users2 WHERE username="'.$users.'"');
    while ($imagefetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($imagequery)) {
        //echo out variables from the above select to make sure you're getting them
        $location = $imagefetch['imagelocation'];
        $image = "<img src='$location' width='60' height='40' />";
        if ($profilename==$username) {
            echo '<div id="hovercolor2" style="width:294px; float:left;"><table><tr>    <td>'.$image.'</td><td><div style="margin-bottom:5px;"><a    href="http://www.pearlsquirrel.com/'.$users.'" target="_blank">'.$users.'</a></div><div><a href="http://www.pearlsquirrel.com/conversation.php/'.$users.'" style="text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank"><div style="font-size:.7em";>Click to enter a conversation.</div></a></div></td></tr></table></div><div id="hrdiv3" style="float:left; width:298px;"></div>';
        } else {
            echo '<div id="hovercolor2" style="width:294px; float:left;"><table><tr><td>'.$image.'</td><td><a href="http://www.pearlsquirrel.com/'.$users.'" target="_blank">'.$users.'</a></td></tr></table></div><div id="hrdiv3" style="float:left; width:298px;"></div>';
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to debug by checking that your values exist when querying the script. Hope this helps

Comment: I wouldn't run nested loops either, it is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Yes nested loops are always a bad idea, your issue is probably this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php#52733

Comment: I took into account what you guys were saying and I simplified my code a bit, but I still have the same problem.  Would you mind looking at it again for me? I will post it up at the top.

Comment: Go here http://www.pearlsquirrel.com/eggo and click the friends tab at the top right of the screen to see the error in action.

Comment: Wasn't imagelocation stored in the users2 table? Did you try and run the code I wrote above? If so what happened? You may want to consider doing a join, it's not that complicated with two tables. Take a look at this resource: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php

Comment: can you post the code around that line where you're getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

The error was not with that piece of code but with an earlier div up on the page where I forgot to end the '.